# Проблема с сохранением в Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Создал небольшой сайт на openserver на двух языках. На openserver русский язык сохранялся нормально и все работало без проблем, но когда перенес на хостинг AVAHOST русский язык весь стал вопросительными знаками, а при редактировании через админ панель слово главная сохраняет в базе как-> Ð“Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð½Ð°Ñ. И так со всеми русскими буквами. Кодировка стоит utf8, в htacces тоже прописал и set_names тоже прописано, на самой базе кодировка utf8 стоит и meta utf8 и в header тоже прописовал, не помогло.В чем проблема? помогите понять

Comment: Подключаетесь к базе как? mysql, mysqli или pdo?

Comment: mysqli_connect()

Comment: попробуйте сделать так mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")

Comment: о да) спасибо огромное спас, помогло

Answer (score -1, accepted):

попробуйте сделать так

```
 mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")
```